# KeyError at / 'cart'

Tags: python-3.x, django

Hola tengo un pequeño error en mi aplicación , les explico cree una tienda virtual y dentro de ella puse una variable global llamada importe total, esta **si el usuario esta autenticado** recorre la clave,valor en la sesión del carrito articulo por articulo y multiplica la cantidad de articulo por el precio, hasta allí todo bien , el tema es cuando cierro sesión e inicio sesión con la misma cuenta o con otro usuario me da el error KeyError at /'cart', pondré en código y me disculpo por la mezcla de ingles español aun estoy practicando

**context_procesor:**

```
def importe_total(request):
    total = 0.0 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        for key,value in request.session['cart'].items():
            total = total +(float(value['precio'])*value['cantidad'])
    return {'importe_total':total}
```

el error en que me da en el navegador al cerrar session y volver a iniciar es este:

```
KeyError at /
'cart'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'cart'
Exception Location: /home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py, line 65, in __getitem__
Python Executable:  /home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/jal/Documentos/Dev/tienda/tienda-master/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf']
Server time:    Thu, 06 May 2021 20:27:53 +0000
```

Lo mas extraño es que si escribo en la url el localhost/tienda y entra normal

**este es el carrito**

````
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get("cart")
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session["cart"] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, producto):
        if (str(producto.id) not in self.cart.keys()):
            self.cart[producto.id] = {
                'producto_id': producto.id,
                'nombre': producto.nombre,
                'cantidad': 1,
                'precio': str(producto.precio),
                'imagen': producto.imagen.url
            }
            

        else:
            for key, value in self.cart.items():
                if key == str(producto.id):
                    value['cantidad'] = value['cantidad'] + 1

                    break

        self.guardar() ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que el error se debe de encontrar en el context processor, ya que estas intentando obtener 'cart' sin saber si ya esta en la sesión, por eso te da 'KeyError' ya que la llave 'cart' no existe en la sesión, para solucionarlo podrías hacer algo asi:

```
def importe_total(request):
    total = 0.0 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:

        if 'cart' in request.session:
            for key,value in request.session['cart'].items():
                total = total +(float(value['precio'])*value['cantidad'])

    return {'importe_total':total}
```